# Adding CSS class through ASPX code

Tags: .net

I am using aspx. If I have HTML as follows:

```
<div id="classMe"></div>
```

I am hoping to dynamically add a css class through the code behind file, i.e. on `Page_Load`. Is it possible?

Comment: Make the `div` to `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a control on serverside make it `runat=server` or even better: use a servercontrol in the first place. In this case you should use a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is rendered as a `div`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelID" CssClass="classMe" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

or from codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PanelID.CssClass = "classMe";
}
```

But if you want to stay with your `div`:

```
<div id="DivID" runat="server"></div>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DivID.Attributes.Add("class", "classMe");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `div` to something like:

```
<div id="classMe" runat="server"></div>
```

Then in your code-behind ASPX.CS file, you can access it.

E.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Access it like this to set a CSS class.
    classMe.Attributes["class"] = "MyCssClass";

    // Access it like this to directly add an inline CSS style:
    classMe.Style.Add("color", "red");
}
```